# Asynchronous closure recursion for structs

Tags: swift, asynchronous, recursion, network-programming, closures

I am writing a network client for Hacker News. I am using their [official API](https://github.com/HackerNews/API).

I am having trouble modifying my network client to work with structs instead of classes for story comments. It works fine with classes, especially with aynchronous recursion closure.

This is my data model.

```
class Comment: Item {
    var replies: [Comment?]?

    let id: Int
    let isDeleted: Bool?
    let parent: Int
    let repliesIDs: [Int]?
    let text: String?
    let time: Date
    let type: ItemType
    let username: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isDeleted = "deleted"
        case id
        case parent
        case repliesIDs = "kids"
        case text
        case time
        case type
        case username = "by"
    }
}
```

This is a sample of my network client.

```
class NetworkClient {
    // ...
    // Top Level Comments
    func fetchComments(for story: Story, completionHandler: @escaping ([Comment]) -> Void) {
        var comments = [Comment?](repeating: nil, count: story.comments!.count)
        
        for (commentIndex, topLevelCommentID) in story.comments!.enumerated() {
            let topLevelCommentURL = URL(string: "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/\(topLevelCommentID).json")!
            
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: topLevelCommentURL) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
                guard let data = data else {
                    print("Invalid top level comment data.")
                    return
                }
                
                do {
                    let comment = try self.jsonDecoder.decode(Comment.self, from: data)
                    comments[commentIndex] = comment
                    
                    if comment.repliesIDs != nil {
                        self.fetchReplies(for: comment) { replies in
                            comment.replies = replies
                        }
                    }
                    
                    self.dispatchGroup.leave()
                } catch {
                    print("There was a problem decoding top level comment JSON.")
                    print(error)
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }.resume()
        }
        
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .global(qos: .userInitiated)) {
            completionHandler(comments.compactMap { $0 })
        }
    }
    
    // Recursive method
    private func fetchReplies(for comment: Comment, completionHandler: @escaping ([Comment?]) -> Void) {
        var replies = [Comment?](repeating: nil, count: comment.repliesIDs!.count)
        
        for (replyIndex, replyID) in comment.repliesIDs!.enumerated() {
            let replyURL = URL(string: "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/\(replyID).json")!
            
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: replyURL) { (data, _, _) in
                guard let data = data else { return }
                
                do {
                    let reply = try self.jsonDecoder.decode(Comment.self, from: data)
                    replies[replyIndex] = reply
                    
                    if reply.repliesIDs != nil {
                        self.fetchReplies(for: reply) { replies in
                            reply.replies = replies
                        }
                    }
                    
                    self.dispatchGroup.leave()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }.resume()
        }
        
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .global(qos: .userInitiated)) {
            completionHandler(replies)
        }
    }
}
```

You call the network client like this for fetching a comment tree for a particular story.

```
var comments = [Comment]()

let networkClient = NetworkClient()
networkClient.fetchStories(from: selectedStory) { commentTree in
    // ...
    comments = commentTree
    // ...
}
```

Switching the Comment class data model to struct does not work nicely with asynchronous closure recursion. It works fine with classes because classes are referenced whereas structs are copied and it causes some problems.

How can I adapt my network client to work with structs? And is there a way to rewrite my methods into a single method instead of two? One method is for the top level (root) comments whilst the other is recursion for each top level (root) comment replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this code block

```swift
let reply = try self.jsonDecoder.decode(Comment.self, from: data)
replies[replyIndex] = reply

if reply.repliesIDs != nil {
    self.fetchReplies(for: reply) { replies in
        reply.replies = replies
    }
}
```

If `Comment` was a struct, this will fetching `reply`, adding a copy of it to the `replies` array, and then, in `fetchReplies` you are mutating the original `reply` (which you must have changed from `let` to `var` for this line to even compile), not the copy in the array.

So, you might want to refer to `replies[replyIndex]` in your `fetchReplies` closure, e.g.:

```swift
let reply = try self.jsonDecoder.decode(Comment.self, from: data)
replies[replyIndex] = reply

if reply.repliesIDs != nil {
    self.fetchReplies(for: reply) { replies in
        replies[replyIndex].replies = replies
    }
}
```

---

By the way,

- dispatch group must not be a property, but rather must be a local var (especially as you appear to be calling this method recursively!);
- you have several paths of execution where you are not leaving the group (if `data` was `nil` or if `reply.repliesIDs` was `nil` or if JSON parsing failed); and
- you have paths of execution where you leave the group prematurely (if `reply.repliesIDs` was not `nil`, you must move the `leave()` call into that completion handler closure).

I have not tested it out, but I would suggest something like:

```
private func fetchReplies(for comment: Comment, completionHandler: @escaping ([Comment?]) -> Void) {
    var replies = [Comment?](repeating: nil, count: comment.repliesIDs!.count)
    let group = DispatchGroup() // local var
    
    for (replyIndex, replyID) in comment.repliesIDs!.enumerated() {
        let replyURL = URL(string: "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/\(replyID).json")!
        
        group.enter()
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: replyURL) { data, _, _ in
            guard let data = data else { 
                group.leave() // leave on failure, too
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let reply = try self.jsonDecoder.decode(Comment.self, from: data)
                replies[replyIndex] = reply
                
                if reply.repliesIDs != nil {
                    self.fetchReplies(for: reply) { replies in
                        replies[replyIndex].replies = replies
                        group.leave() // if reply.replieIDs was not nil, we must not `leave` until this is done
                    }
                } else {
                    group.leave() // leave if reply.repliesIDs was nil
                }
            } catch {
                group.leave() // leave on failure, too
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) { // do this on main to avoid synchronization headaches
        completionHandler(replies)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've tried your suggestions and it doesn't work. I printed the value before and after for that one line `replies[replyIndex].replies = replies`. Before prints `nil` and after prints `Optional([nil])`

Comment: I also tried force unwrapping as well. `replies[replyIndex]!.replies = replies` It was initially like this `replies[replyIndex]?.replies = replies`

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to unwrap it.

Comment: By the way, all the dispatch group issues I pointed out in `fetchReplies` applies to `fetchComments`, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob! I've adjusted other parts of my app and it is working as expected.